# In Rails 4, how can I create an Active Record object and an associated has_many object at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's two models:

```
class TeachingResource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links

  validates_presence_of :links
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :teaching_resource

  validates_presence_of :teaching_resource
end
```

The idea is that every `TeachingResource` must have at least one `Link`.

I am trying to create them both at the same time like this:

```
tr = TeachingResource.new({title: 'blah', description: 'blah'})
tr.links.build({href: 'whatever'})
tr.save!

# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Resource objective links teaching resource can't be blank
```

If I remove the `validates_presence_of :teaching_resource` then it will save, but if I do this in an Rspec test: `expect(tr).to be_valid`, then this happens:

```
# Links Each teaching resource must have at least one link
```

Which is the custom error message I assigned for the validation above.

It seems that the TeachingResource id is not being added to the new Link as it's created. Is this by design? What's the proper way to create two records like this?

Comment: are you trying to create them both at the same time in controller or in a unit test?

Comment: Try reloading the record after it's saved: `expect(tr.reload).to be_valid`

Comment: Still not valid after reload

Comment: Unit test at the moment. Controller after these pass

Comment: Not that this is a helpful comment - but every time I have implemented a `has_many` that requires one or more items via validation - it continually causes issues in both testing and production code, consider using a conditional validation that is only enabled in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

After replicating your associations they seem to be running fine:

```
describe Link, type: :model do
  let!(:teaching_resource) {FactoryGirl.build(:teaching_resource)}
  let!(:link){ teaching_resource.links.build}

  it "test" do
    expect(teaching_resource.persisted?).to be_falsey
    expect(teaching_resource.links.length).to eq(1)
    expect(teaching_resource).to be_valid
  end


class TeachingResource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links
  validates :links, presence: true
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teaching_resource
  validates :teaching_resource, presence: true
end
```

Try copy/pasting this and see if the tests pass

Associations are also declared in factories, but since I'm using build that does not change anything.

rails: 4.2.5, ruby: 2.2.2